# Can't access data inside Ajax jquery function after rendering partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

The problem is I can't access data fetched in Ajax correctly I need to access data by data.responseJSONfrom.follow and I would like to do it by data.follow

```
def create
 follow = current_user.user_followings.new(following_id:params[:following_id])
 status = follow.save
 render json: {follow: status ? render_to_string(partial: 'users/follow', locals:{follow: follow, id_to_follow: follow.following_id }) : ''},
             status: status ? :ok : :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

```
$('#unfollow').bind('ajax:complete', function(xhr, data){
      $(this).replaceWith(data.follow);
 });
```

data.follow is unresolved variable

Comment: What do you see when you add `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Something like {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} with a lot of methods and responseJSON and responseText

Comment: How about `console.log(data['follow']);`?

Comment: it says undefined :)

Comment: Well, there you go. Not sure if that gets you any closer to solving the problem, but you might start there :)

Comment: Penny! The problem was with .bind method :) I switched to .on and now it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start by debugging your `data` object in the console:
`console.log('data: ', data);` should be returning the data that you need. If not, something is wrong with the response or the method.

Just posting this as an answer in case anyone else has a similar problem. The problem is that you need to change your AJAX listener function from `.bind()` to `.on()`.

So in your case:

```
$('#unfollow').on('ajax:complete', function(xhr, data){
  $(this).replaceWith(data.follow);
});
```